# Flagging rows that contain filepath in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem trying to flag all the rows from a table.
The first column it is the filepath of a folder and it is as following Folder1\Folder2\Folder3.
The second column contain information about how many folders are in a folder.
And the third column contain information about how many documents are in a folder.

I should mark all rows that have 0 documents, but a folder can contain multiple folders, and one of these folders contains a document, then the initial folder should not be marked.

As example please see the following structure:

```sql
Select * from (
VALUES
('Folder 1','2','1'),
('Folder 1\Folder 1','0','0'),
('Folder 1\Folder 2','2','4'),
('Folder 1\Folder 2\Folder 1','0','2'),
('Folder 1\Folder 2\Folder 2','0','0'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3','2','0'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 1','3','0'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 1\Folder 1','0','1'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 1\Folder 2','0','0'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 1\Folder 3','0','3'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 2','2','0'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 2\Folder 1','0','0'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 2\Folder 2','0','0')
)
as currentFormat(folderPath, numberOfFolders, numberOfDocuments)
```

I tried to create a hierarchy from the first column but I did not reach any result. I also tried with ranking functions but still the same without any results.
I am accepting any kind of solution that can fix my problem, including T-SQL code or stored procedures only with the condition that the code can be run in Sql Server.

For the example above, the desired output should be the following:

```sql
Select * from (
VALUES
('Folder 1','2','1','Keep'),
('Folder 1\Folder 1','0','0','Delete'),
('Folder 1\Folder 2','2','4','Keep'),
('Folder 1\Folder 2\Folder 1','0','2','Keep'),
('Folder 1\Folder 2\Folder 2','0','0','Delete'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3','2','0','Keep'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 1','3','0','Keep'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 1\Folder 1','0','1','Keep'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 1\Folder 2','0','0','Delete'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 1\Folder 3','0','3','Keep'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 2','2','0','Delete'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 2\Folder 1','0','0','Delete'),
('Folder 1\Folder 3\Folder 2\Folder 2','0','0','Delete')
)
as output(folderPath, numberOfFolders, numberOfDocuments,flag)
```

Comment: Why are all of the numbers strings (`'0'`) rather than integers (`0`)? Your description says "mark the rows" and the desired output has `'Keep'` and `'Delete'`. What do they mean? What of a folder contains more than two subfolders? Have you tried a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) to walk from the bottom of the tree (highest number of solidi) back to the top?

Comment: 'Keep' and 'Delete' it's the flag I need to put. The numbers are strings because they come from a csv.

Comment: Please have a look at [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a6dvlPr4) and see how your explanation might begin to translate into code.

Comment: Thank you @HABO! I was a bit unclear and I am sorry for that, I edited my post. The logic behind the Keep/Delete flag should be, if a folder don't have a document in it delete, if a folder have a folder that have an document in it keep.